# How to view the Doughnut Chart in c# and the data is from the database?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am currently having trouble loading the doughnut and column chart in my program. All the data were from my database Table Reports. When I run the program there is no chart found and only the data grid view is showing. No errors/issues were also indicated when running it.

this is the code that I'm using.

```cs
con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LAPTOP-KA7UGSG3;Initial Catalog=imsysdb;Integrated Security=True");
con.Open();
cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO reports (Variety, Quantity) SELECT Variety, SUM(Quantity) FROM Inventory GROUP BY Variety", con);

Quantity_Chart.Series["Variety"].XValueMember = "Variety";
Quantity_Chart.Series["Variety"].YValueMembers = "Quantity";
Quantity_Chart.DataSource = imsysdbDataSet2.reports;
Quantity_Chart.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Data from databse => modelList

```
            string[] x = (from p in modelList.AsEnumerable()
                          orderby p.Field<string>("STATUS") ascending
                          select p.Field<string>("STATUS")).ToArray();

            //Get the Total of Orders for each City.
            int[] y = (from p in modelList.AsEnumerable()
                       orderby p.Field<string>("STATUS") ascending
                       select p.Field<int>("Total")).ToArray();


            chart2.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Doughnut;
            chart2.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
            chart2.Legends[0].Enabled = true;
            chart2.ChartAreas[0].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
```